# How to create a button with different types of animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm totally novice in animation. Please find the below GIF represenation for the same.

[image: GIF]

How to create a animated button like below GIF image ? I am not aware how to start this animation.

Please help me in creating this animation

Are there any third part libraries are code available? if so could you please healp me on this.

Comment: Well you can start off with CoreAnimation like CABasicAnimation or CAKeyFrameAimation and then figure out the rest on ur own :)

Comment: Are there any 3rd party classes which can animate like this?

Comment: not really sure buddy moreover it looks more like custom animation to ur app these are not standard components so I dont think all find off the shelf components for these animations

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=button

Comment: Correct the grammar and adding more text.